# Multiple \if condition using etoolbox

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

**First:** I've found "[Checking if two conditionals are met](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37375/checking-if-two-conditionals-are-met)" but I don't know how to change it do suit my needs.

**Wanted:** I have eight different predefined values and I want different definitions of a constant dependnig on the eight values.

[image: wanted]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\noindent Define the following:
\begin{verbatim}
\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}
\end{verbatim}
What I want:
\begin{verbatim}
\cumuA > 75         : \def\quartileC{0}
\cumuA < 75 < \cumuB: \def\quartileC{1}
\cumuB < 75 < \cumuC: \def\quartileC{2}
\cumuC < 75 < \cumuD: \def\quartileC{3}
\cumuD < 75 < \cumuE: \def\quartileC{4}
\cumuE < 75 < \cumuF: \def\quartileC{5}
\cumuF < 75 < \cumuG: \def\quartileC{6}
\cumuG < 75 < \cumuH: \def\quartileC{7}
\end{verbatim}
This should then result in
\begin{verbatim}
\def\quartileC{3}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I guess that [`etoolbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is the way to go here but (as said before) I don't know how use it properly for this task.

Comment: When using basic (kernel) conditionals, the key here is to compare dimensions, since `\cumuX` contain decimals. As such, `\ifdim` (with some unit of measure like `pt` as an appendage) rather that `\ifnum`.

Comment: @Werner Good point. Any chance I can make you work some magic using `etoolbox` regarding my question, even though I've already accepted another answer? `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this update I add a second simple no package method. As in the other answers naturally I use `\ifdim` because I need to compare fixed point numbers.

Let me first point out that your conditions should read `\cumuA >= 75`,  then `\cumuA<75<=\cumuB` then `\cumuB<75<=\cumuC` etc... (i.e. not only strict inequalities).

Notice that `TeX` has no direct proviso for testing `>=` or `<=` : the programmer is suppose to negate the result of testing, respectively `<` or `>` thanks to the `\else`. Or there is `\unless` from e-TeX (not used in my answer).

In both approaches I arrange things to test only one inequality at each step. First approach, the most simple minded:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}

\def\quartileC{7}%
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuG pt\else\def\quartileC{6}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuF pt\else\def\quartileC{5}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuE pt\else\def\quartileC{4}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuD pt\else\def\quartileC{3}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuC pt\else\def\quartileC{2}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuB pt\else\def\quartileC{1}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuA pt\else\def\quartileC{0}\fi

quartileC: \quartileC
\end{document}
```

> [image]

The second approach uses some delimited macros borrowed from code of `xint`.

```
\long\def\DOTHIS #1#2\ORTHAT #3{\fi #1}%
\makeatletter
\let\ORTHAT\@firstofone
\makeatother
```

The advantage of the second approach is to allow also, if desired, the easy definition of an expandable one-parameter macro `\mypercentile` which will be used as

```
\edef\quartileC {\mypercentile{75}}
```

for example. This is added at bottom.

1. for this I needed to add spaces after each `pt` from the first posted version, as TeX inserts a non expandable `\relax` token if not. (This changed nothing to the original functioning, but has to be done if one wants the `\mypercentile` thing).
2. the expandability is in the strongest sense (`` \romannumeral-`0 `` will fully expand `\mypercentile`).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

% MACROS TAKEN WITH NEW NAMES FROM XINT CODE BY JFBU
\long\def\DOTHIS #1#2\ORTHAT #3{\fi #1}%
\makeatletter
\let\ORTHAT\@firstofone
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent Define the following:
\begin{verbatim}
\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}
\end{verbatim}
\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}

What I want:
\begin{verbatim}
\cumuA > 75         : \def\quartileC{0}% I meant \cumuA>=75 here
\cumuA < 75 < \cumuB: \def\quartileC{1}% I want  \cumuA < 75 <= \cumuB
\cumuB < 75 < \cumuC: \def\quartileC{2}% rather: \cumuB < 75 <= \cumuC
\cumuC < 75 < \cumuD: \def\quartileC{3}
\cumuD < 75 < \cumuE: \def\quartileC{4}
\cumuE < 75 < \cumuF: \def\quartileC{5}
\cumuF < 75 < \cumuG: \def\quartileC{6}
\cumuG < 75 < \cumuH: \def\quartileC{7}
\end{verbatim}
This should then result in
\begin{verbatim}
\def\quartileC{3}
\end{verbatim}

I do:
\begin{verbatim}
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuA pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{0}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuB pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{1}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuC pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{2}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuD pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{3}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuE pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{4}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuF pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{5}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuG pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{6}}\fi
\ORTHAT{\def\quartileC{7}}%
\end{verbatim}

(The spaces after ``pt'' were added in an edit; they do not matter here but
are useful for expandable wrapper \string\mypercentile).
% EDIT ADDS SPACE AFTER pt TO AVOID TEX INSERTION OF \relax
% (which does not matter here but does in the expanable wrapper
% \mypercentile next)

\ifdim 75pt>\cumuA pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{0}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuB pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{1}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuC pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{2}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuD pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{3}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuE pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{4}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuF pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{5}}\fi
\ifdim 75pt>\cumuG pt \else\DOTHIS{\def\quartileC{6}}\fi
\ORTHAT{\def\quartileC{7}}%

and I obtain that \texttt{\string\quartileC} has meaning
\texttt{\meaning\quartileC}.


\clearpage

\def\mypercentile #1{%
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuA pt \else\DOTHIS{0}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuB pt \else\DOTHIS{1}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuC pt \else\DOTHIS{2}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuD pt \else\DOTHIS{3}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuE pt \else\DOTHIS{4}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuF pt \else\DOTHIS{5}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuG pt \else\DOTHIS{6}\fi
\ORTHAT{7}%
}

\edef\quartileC{\mypercentile{75}}
\edef\quartileB{\mypercentile{50}}
\edef\quartileA{\mypercentile{25}}

\ttfamily

\string\quartileC{} has meaning \meaning\quartileC.

\string\quartileB{} has meaning \meaning\quartileB.

\string\quartileA{} has meaning \meaning\quartileA.

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

```
\def\mypercentile #1{%
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuA pt \else\DOTHIS{0}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuB pt \else\DOTHIS{1}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuC pt \else\DOTHIS{2}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuD pt \else\DOTHIS{3}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuE pt \else\DOTHIS{4}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuF pt \else\DOTHIS{5}\fi
\ifdim #1pt>\cumuG pt \else\DOTHIS{6}\fi
\ORTHAT{7}%
}

\edef\quartileC{\mypercentile{75}}
\edef\quartileB{\mypercentile{50}}
\edef\quartileA{\mypercentile{25}}
```

> [image: page 2]

Answer (score 2):

The following is an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) implimentation using

```
\ifdimcomp{<dimA>}{<relation>}{<dimB>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

> quartileC: 3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}

% \ifdimcomp{<dimA>}{<relation>}{<dimB>}{<true>}{<false>}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuA pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{0}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuA pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuB pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{1}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuB pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuC pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{2}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuC pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuD pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{3}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuD pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuE pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{4}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuE pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuF pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{5}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuF pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuG pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{6}}{}}{}
\ifdimcomp{\cumuG pt}<{75pt}{\ifdimcomp{\cumuH pt}>{75pt}{\def\quartileC{7}}{}}{}

quartileC: \quartileC

\end{document}
```

Nested conditions allow for an `and`-like boolean operation.

Answer (score 2):

An alteration to [Ahmed's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37674/5764) in [Checking if two conditionals are met](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37375/5764) for numbers to make it work with this case and using "dimensions":

> quartileC: 3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\def\dimtest#1and#2#{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\cpt@dimlt\cpt@dimgt\cpt@dimeq#1%
    \cpt@removetonnil<=>\cpt@nnil\relax
    \ifdim\dimexpr\cpt@dimlt\cpt@dimgt\cpt@dimeq#2%
      \cpt@removetonnil<=>\cpt@nnil\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\cumuA{33.3}
\def\cumuB{59.5}
\def\cumuC{73.8}
\def\cumuD{83.3}
\def\cumuE{88.1}
\def\cumuF{90.5}
\def\cumuG{97.6}
\def\cumuH{100}

\dimtest \cumuA pt>75pt and 0pt=0pt {\def\quartileC{0}}{}
\dimtest \cumuA pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuB pt{\def\quartileC{1}}{}
\dimtest \cumuB pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuC pt{\def\quartileC{2}}{}
\dimtest \cumuC pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuD pt{\def\quartileC{3}}{}
\dimtest \cumuD pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuE pt{\def\quartileC{4}}{}
\dimtest \cumuE pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuF pt{\def\quartileC{5}}{}
\dimtest \cumuF pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuG pt{\def\quartileC{6}}{}
\dimtest \cumuG pt<75pt and 75pt<\cumuH pt{\def\quartileC{7}}{}

quartileC: \quartileC

\end{document}
```